# An efficient way to find the largest set of people and the meeting time given a set of free intervals, meeting length and max people allowed

Tags: python, algorithm

Let us say that I have a list of people and their free time intervals

```
    free_time = { 
                A:[(1,5)(7,9)]
                B:[(2,10)]
                C:[(1,3),(5,10)]
                D:[(1,4),(8,10)]
        }
```

Given the meeting length is 3 and max people allowed is 3.
The output will be :-

```
Participants:[A,B] 
Meeting at (2,5)
```

**Edit:**
Even though [A,D] is also a solution, I need to pick the people in the order given only. The program should return 1 set of participants only

Even though the max people allowed is 3. We could find only 2 people.

The program should output the earliest meeting time.
The program need ton only find first max_allowed number of people that satisfy the constraint.

Is there any efficient way to do this without going through all the combination of people

Comment: Constraints on number of people and number of free-time intervals?

Comment: Also, if there were, lets say, max_allowed=3 and possible people who satisfy that free time frame were, 5 (say, A,B,C,D,E), what should be the output?

Comment: If max_allowed = 3 then program can output the first 3 people found. We can take the order of the people itself as their priority. What do you mean by constraint on number of free-time intervals?

Comment: Nevermind that...but in that case, this seems like a fairly str fwd problem to me. Since you have not tagged any language, I'll give you a pythonic pseudocode to solve this

Comment: python is great. The problem I am seeing is if we do a naïve approach it seems to take a lot of time >10 mins for 18 people and max_allowed=5.

Comment: Oh, I can do much better. Wait for it.

Comment: There is another issue with your question now. If meeting_length is specified (3) and max_allowed is 3, shouldn't the output be: `meeting: (1,3), participants: A,C,D`

Comment: C only has (1,3) as freetime whose length is 3-1 = 2.

Comment: Oh, ok, so we include 1st value but exclude last - OK. Still, answer should be `meeting: (1,3), participants: A,D`. If not, why?

Comment: meeting cannot be held at (1,3) because it has length of 2 only

Comment: Oh, my bad. I meant (1,4)

Comment: yea, it is also a solution. But we can take the first solution in the order of people.

Answer (score 0):

I have a python based solution for you. Try this:

```
def can_attend(free_list, meet_iv):
    free_list.sort()
    for iv in free_list:
        if iv[0] <= meet_iv[0] and iv[1] >= meet_iv[1]:
            return True
    return False

free_time = {A: ...,}
persons = free_time.keys()
meeting = (2,5)
max_allowed = 3
attendees = []

for person in persons:
    if can_attend(free_time[person], meeting):
        attendees.append(person)
    if len(attendees) == max_allowed:
        break

print(attendees)
```

This is pretty straight forward IMO. If there is any confusion, feel free to ask in comments and I'll explain. (Variable names should help)

Comment: I am really sorry. I think I was not clear with the question. The meeting time is also part of the output. The program should find a earliest meeting time in which it can schedule the meeting for maximum people <= max_allowed

Comment: Isn't meeting time your input? How long should be this meeting?

Comment: length of meeting only. in this case it is 3

Comment: Oh dear!! You just changed the whole scope of the question.

Comment: I'll try and figure something out

Comment: Sorry for that. I think first it was not that clear. Thanks!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/241664/discussion-between-nicky97-and-vish4071).